# Cassandra NodeTool cfstats count

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I have created a cassandra table like so, with lots of information:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.table1 (
uuid blob,
id bigint,
timestamp bigint,
description text,
option1 double,
PRIMARY KEY (uuid, id) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I am trying to run nodetool cfstats on it to determine the row count. I searched online and it seems like that number of keys(estimate) should be the row count. However, the number is very low as shown below, so I know that this can't be right. What am I doing wrong?

```
Table: table1
    SSTable count: 3
    Space used (live): 195.02 MB
    Space used (total): 195.02 MB
    Space used by snapshots (total): 567.99 KB
    Off heap memory used (total): 61.83 KB
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.3936987749701019
    Number of keys (estimate): 19
    Memtable cell count: 612048
    Memtable data size: 14.18 MB
    Memtable off heap memory used: 0 bytes
    Memtable switch count: 6
    Local read count: 2657130
    Local read latency: 0.055 ms
    Local write count: 2409743
    Local write latency: 0.017 ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Bloom filter false positives: 0
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 64 bytes
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 40 bytes
    Index summary off heap memory used: 84 bytes
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 61.71 KB
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 49.82 KB
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 85.8 MB
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 27.06 MB
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0160752060827343
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 5722
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
```

If this is not possible, is there another way to get the row count of a table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your schema your Partition Key is your uuid column. Each Partition Key is a "Row" to the Cassandra storage engine. So cfstats is simply outputting the number of partition keys (estimated of course) that is stored for this table.

I would check and see how many distinct UUIDs you have in your system, if it's around 19, then everything is good.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the row count?

Comment: Distributed databases like Cassandra don't count things very well. I don't know what problems you are trying to solve by counting, but if you want to stick with Cassandra I would suggest your re-evaluate those requirements. For extra info on the topic I would suggest reading : http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/counting-key-in-cassandra/

Comment: Ok, since my primary key is a combination of UUID and id, shouldn't there be more keys outputted from nodetool netstats?

Comment: Your schema defines uuid as a partition key, and id is a clustering key. Cfstats can only count the number of partition keys, because again that is a "row" to the storage engine. Clustering columns are a means to define wide rows in Cassandra, which are all stored under their partition key.

Comment: Ok thanks! One more question I had, is there anyway to determine the last x amount of rows that were inserted into the table without knowing anything else about the table?

Comment: Again due to the design goals of Cassandra that is hard to do. If that's a requirement of sorts I would suggest having a table using the [bucketed time series data model pattern] (https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling). And possibly add a text column that stores the cql that was executed.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the number of "rows", its the number if keys or partitions. In your data model it would be the number of unique `uuid`'s. Note that for 2.0 this number can be off a bit, it will sum up the number of partitions in all sstables. [Post 2.1.6](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9107) it will merge a hyperloglog structure so duplicates across sstables will not impact it.

To get the CQL row you actually need to read the data, you can use [count](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__counting-returned-rows) or a spark job, these are expensive so may want to consider keeping an alternative table with a counter in it.

Comment: The count operation takes too long, so can I get it any other way? If I have to use the count operation, how do I make sure it doesn't time out. I am willing to wait.

Comment: you can increase the read timeout in `cassandra.yaml` and your driver timeout. It will be trouble ultimately though for anything outside of daily analytic checks or something. Its hard to tell exactly what your trying to do but a `((uuid, id), timestamp)` will let you see the latest X changes (add a limit to a query with a given uuid/id) and then the estimated keys will be closer to what you want (in 2.1+).